# HTML Canvas - Text moving and showing layers behind based on mouse movement

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

This is going to be a short one. Basically, I am trying to recreate the Y as seen on the homepage of this site - https://yalantis.com/.

I've never used Canvas before and am not very proficient with JS.

I've managed to draw a canvas and got as far as getting the shape I want and a rotate animation but I cannot seem to find a source that explains how the canvas is moving on the yalantis site.

This is what I have done so far:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
// create mouse event listener
const mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 };
function mouseEvents(e) {
  const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  mouse.x = e.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;
  mouse.y = e.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;
}
document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseEvents);

// draw design at x,y and rotated by angle
function drawRotated(x, y, angle) {
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, y);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.beginPath();
  // ctx.arc(0, 0, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  // ctx.moveTo(-100, 0);
  // ctx.lineTo(100, 0);
  // ctx.lineTo(60, -80);
  // ctx.stroke();
  ctx.font = '600pt Rig Sans';
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.strokeText('W', x, y);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
}

// render loop called 60 times a second
function update(timer) {
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // reset transform
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);

  // get angle from center to mouse
  var angle = Math.atan2(mouse.y - 150, mouse.x - 150);

  // draw rotated design
  drawRotated(150, 150, angle);
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);



  $('#canvas').attr('height', $(document).height());
  $('#canvas').attr('width', $(document).width());
```

Although this is also a bit of a bust since it's duplicating itself on every mousemove and rotating on the spot in a weird position.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something similar to this by drawing multiple letters and then offsetting them based on mouse position.

In the mouse position I offset the x and y by the position of the drawn letter, in this case the center of the canvas.

```
    mouse.x = e.x - bounds.x - canvas.width/2;
    mouse.y = e.y - bounds.y - canvas.height/2;
```

So when my mouse is positioned over the middle of the letter it appears as one letter. Now in my loop to create each letter I can use the `i` to offset each iteration. Dividing by 10 is just a number I picked to keep the letters from moving too much. Same with multiplying `i*0.25`. That's just based on what I thought looked good for how far each letter moves from the one before.

```
    ctx.strokeText('W', x - (mouse.x/10*(i*0.25)), y - (mouse.y/10*(i*0.25)));
    ctx.fillText('W', x - (mouse.x/10*(i*0.25)), y - (mouse.y/10*(i*0.25)));
```

You'll see the further away the mouse gets from the center of the letter the more spread each iteration of letter has.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = innerWidth;
canvas.height = innerHeight;
let bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
// create mouse event listener
const mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 };
function mouseEvents(e) {
  bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  mouse.x = e.x - bounds.x - canvas.width / 2;
  mouse.y = e.y - bounds.y - canvas.height / 2;
}
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseEvents);

// draw design at x,y and rotated by angle
function drawRotated(x, y) {
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.font = "300pt Rig Sans";
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.shadowColor = "rgb(255, 153, 51)";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 153, 51, 0.2)";
  let j = 1;
  for (let i = 7; i > 1; i--) {
    ctx.lineWidth = j;
    ctx.shadowBlur = j;
    ctx.strokeText(
      "W",
      x - (mouse.x / 10) * (i * 0.25),
      y - (mouse.y / 10) * (i * 0.25)
    );
    ctx.fillText(
      "W",
      x - (mouse.x / 10) * (i * 0.25),
      y - (mouse.y / 10) * (i * 0.25)
    );
    ctx.closePath();
    j++
  }
}

function update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // draw rotated design
  drawRotated(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2 + 100);
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
update();

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  canvas.width = innerWidth;
  canvas.height = innerHeight;
});
//$('#canvas').attr('height', $(document).height());
//$('#canvas').attr('width', $(document).width());
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

There may be a better way to do this but it's something to get you started.

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I also updated the snippet because I noticed the example seems to fade out the further back it gets. Mine was actually the opposite. Now the front letter is the thickest and the back letter is the thinnest.